# How to add a Network storage NFS DATA store to ESXI?

Tags: system-administration, esxi

I have NAS storage, created with a share to mount the NFS at ESXi host,

Trying to mount I get the following error:

> `Failed to mount NFS datastore Test - Operation failed, diagnostics report: Unable to resolve hostname 'nfs://<NFS Server IP>/nfs/nfs_share`

Answer (score 0):

--> New DataStore

--> Mount NFS datastore

```
-- NAME: your referred Name
--NFS SERVER: your NFS Server IP
--NFS Share: /nfs/<your share folder name>
--Version: NFS 3
```

That's it.

Comment: Not saying this is wrong: I don't understand it. Can you please elaborate on `--> New DataStore` and `--> Mount NFS datastore`, seeing the question is tagged [tag:esxi]?

Comment: Those are the options while adding a new datastore, I have mentioned like steps.